# need to change input names to input id's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to change a calculation from input name(s) to input id(s).
The old input name was "ef-fee".
The new id is "ef-fee_" +[i]);

The old code using input names:

```
<script async> //Entrance Fees 

function findTotalEF(){
var arrEF = document.getElementsByName('ef-fee');
var totEF=0;

for(var i=0; i<arrEF.length; i++){


if(parseInt(arrEF[i].value)) totEF += parseInt(arrEF[i].value);}
document.getElementById('totalEF').value = totEF;
}
```

This is the new code which doesn't work:

```
<script async> //Entrance Fees 

function findTotalEF(){

var totEF=0;    

for (i=0; i <=48; i++) 


if ($('#ef-fee_' + i > 0)) {totEF += "ef-fee_"  +[i].val;} // This line is not correct. Can someone please fix it?

document.getElementById('totalEF').value = totEF;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should do what you are needing

```
function findTotalEF() {
  var totEF = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= 48; i++) {
    var $input = $('#ef-fee_' + i);
    var value =  parseInt($input.val()) || 0;
    totEF += value > 0 ? value : 0; 
  }
  $('#totalEF').val(totEF);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't display the totals. Please go to verlager.com, click on the folder icon to load the data, and hold {tab} to populate the form. See that there are no totals at the top of the page.

Comment: My bad...Small typo ... change `input.val()` to `$input.val()` .. working version http://jsfiddle.net/93an1m64/7/

Comment: Gosh, it still displays "0" instead of the total efs.

Comment: Are you calling this after they all exist? And have values set?

Comment: Yes. The form gets populated. Various players pay differing amounts. And the accountant wants the totals.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177459/discussion-between-verlager-and-charlietfl).